# apt pinning package versions

Tags: debian, apt

Is it possible to pin a version of a debian package?

Is it possible to pin only the major version? (like with `pip install "pyramid < 1.4.0"` will install the latest 1.3.x but will not upgrade the major version)?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can do this, for example, by creating a file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/yourpackage` as

```
Package: yourpackage
Pin: version 7.*
Pin-Priority: 999
```

This would allow upgrades to `yourpackage` to versions matching 7.*

Comment: Thanks so needed this. TBH I google a bit and cannot find some definitive and comprehensive doc for apt pinning apart from tutorials which are sometimes too specific and random docs here and there. Is there some official doc anywhere?

Comment: Haven't seen much other than: man apt_preferences

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto